# Adding a Trendline to Bar Chart in Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts

How do I go about adding a trendline to a bar chart in reporting services 2005?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the data for the trend line from your datasource.

From the Chart properties, on the data tab, select the trend data series. Click edit and on the 'Edit Chart value' Dialogue select the 'appearance' tab. Check the box 'Plot data as line'. Set the line properties using the 'Series Stule' button.