# SSRS:How to Add a Trend Line Series to Chart which has only 1 Point on X Axis

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

The reason I need this is,my chart is inside a Tablix and Only 1 Value(X-axis point) gets supplied to each Row

I can see this line which is centered to chart(as per X-axis) .I want it to run from (X,Y)(0,0) till end of Chart

Comment: Does this answer help at all?

[Adding a Trendline to Bar Chart in Reporting Services][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181027/adding-a-trendline-to-bar-chart-in-reporting-services

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Julio,Thanks. I had same thought, so took a step back and got around the problem using Stripline property on vertical axis

Answer (score 0):

Pavan,

The trend line is the result of a linear regression and, as such, will need more than one observation in order to be calculated.

For a cloud of data to define the line that represents its trend (a trend line must be unique, that is why I refer to it as "the" trend line, and not "a" trend line), it is necessary that there are, at least, two points in it. With one point you can draw an infinite number of lines - no unique solution.

Anyway, if you want simply a line - and not specifilcally the trend line - you can add a series to your graph with a given number of repetitions of your single value.

Hope this helped...

Julio